# How to remove double rectangle from artboard in Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, artboard

There's this double rectangle centered on my focused artboard.
how can i remove it?

screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those lines are Print Tiling guides. They're designed to help you print a single design over multiple pages. For more information on Print Tiling in Illustrator check out the [Viewing Artwork](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6329a.html#WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6327a) article within the Adobe Help section.

To hide the guides, select `Hide Print Tiling` from the `View` menu.

[image]