# Dashed line when changing artboard size in Adobe XD

Tags: creative-cloud, artboard, adobe-xd

I'm using Adobe XD and every time I start a new project I select the dimensions of my Artboard in the small screen that appears every time I open Adobe XD.

If I want to change those dimensions later in the project a dashed line appears as you can see in the picture. Does anyone knows why that happens and how can I get rid of it?

[image: Adobe XD Artboard]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove double rectangle from artboard in Illustrator CC?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35051/how-to-remove-double-rectangle-from-artboard-in-illustrator-cc)

Answer (score 2):

Choose your artboard by using the moving arrow (shortcut: <kbd>V</kbd>), look at the panel on the right side, choose "None" instead of "Vertical" in the Scrolling section.

Answer (score 1):

The dotted line indicates the start of scrollable content. Since you're designing for specified screen sizes, anything below that is implied to be "below the fold".

> If your content continues further than the prescribed length of the artboard, you can simply drag the bottom of the artboard down to the desired length, and continue to design.
>
> A dotted line on your artboard indicates the start of the scrollable content.

- [**Adobe XD Help / Working with artboards**](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-design/help/working-with-artboards.html#Createartboards)

*Note, I've never used Adobe XD, This is just from reading the help docs.*

Answer (score 0):

Cai is correct. I would also like to add, if you don't want the scrollable content (and the dashed line which works simply as a guidance), press <kbd>A</kbd> to create an Artboard and set up a custom size for your needs and make your work in there. When choosing this way, you won't have any dashed lines after resizing your artboard, but you won't have any scrollable content either.